# Bad use of Javax methods

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have this code and it's really ugly. I would like to know what other options can I use instead of this one? I am calling like 100 methods in a single procedure. Is there a way to change it?

```
  javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPaneBallCountroperties);
    jPaneBallCountroperties.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabelBallCount).addComponent(jLabelBallCountExplode))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(backgroundColorLabel,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                    jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(10, 10, 10).addGroup(jPanel3Layout
                                            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabelBallCountField,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(jLabelExplodeCountField,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addContainerGap()));
    jPanel3Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL,
            new java.awt.Component[] { jLabelBallCount, jLabelBallCountExplode });
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabelBallCount).addComponent(jLabelBallCountField,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabelBallCountExplode).addComponent(jLabelExplodeCountField,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(backgroundColorLabel,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
    pack();
}
```

Comment: Couldnt you store some of the values? (Im not a java expert): int l=javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFFEREDSIZE;

Comment: Don't use the IDE to generate the GUI code. The code is always cleaner, better structured and easier to maintain when you write the layout code manually. And the code will be portable if you ever move to a different IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably consider splitting up your GUI into multiple classes. I also think your code would be easier to read if you use imports. Example:

```
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE;
```

If it's your IDE that has generated this, your should probably just close your eyes and forget about this code or just rewrite it yourself and not let your IDE do it.

I would never let an IDE generate my GUI code...